# How can a constructor from the subclass access a private field variable from the superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

It was my understanding that a subclass can only inherit field variables if its protected. From the UML diagram on my textbook I'm practicing with, it has the field variables of the superclass private and is accessed by the subclass' constructor without creating an error... How?

```
public class GeometricObject {
    private String _colour;
    private boolean _filled;
    private Date _dateCreated;

    //Constructors
    public GeometricObject() {}

    public GeometricObject(String colour, boolean filled) {
        this._colour = colour;
        this._filled = filled;
}
    ...
}


public class Circle extends GeometricObject{
   private double _radius;

   //Constructors
   public Circle() {}

   public Circle(String colour, boolean filled, double radius) {
      super(colour, filled);
      this._radius = radius;
}
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is the code you posted supposed to show "field variables of the superclass private and is accessed by the subclass' constructor"? It doesn't.

Comment: subclasses still have those variables even if you can't access them.  `super` calls the constructor of the parent class and said constructor *can* access those private variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because:

- `Circle` is accessing public constructor of  `GenericObject`
- the `color` and `filled` are parameters of `GenericObject` constructor used by `Circle` and not properties of super class `GenericObject`.
- It would be wrong to say the using `super()` `Circle` is accessing the fields of `GenericObject`. It is setting them using constructor.

Answer (score -1):

The Circle is extends GeometricObject, so the Circle can use **Property** of GeometricObject, but not the GeometricObject **data** .

its still Circle **data** .